# Audio file reading for FFT

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

first time asking though i have been visiting for some time.

Here's the problem:

I'm currently trying to isolate the base frequenciy of a signal contained in a WAVE data file with these properties:

- PCM Audio Format i.e Liner Quantization
- 8000 Hz Sample Rate
- 16 Bits Per Sample
- 16000 Byte Rate

One Channel only there is no interleaving.

Getting the byte value:

```
System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"c:\tet\fft.wav");
        byte[] data = new byte[WaveFile.Length];
        WaveFile.Read(data,0,Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));
```

Converting it to an Array of Doubles:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 32768; i++)//this is only for a relatively small chunk of the file 
        {
           InReal[i] =BitConverter.ToDouble(data, (i + 1) * 8 + 44);
        }
```

and finanly passing it to a Transform Function.

```
       FFT FftObject = new FFT();
       FftObject.Transform(InReal, InImg, 0, 32768, out outReal, out outImg, false);
```

Now the first question, as i understand the PCM values of the wav file should be in the boundaries of
-1 and 1, but when converting to Double i get this values:

```
 2.65855908666825E-235
 2.84104982662944E-285
-1.58613492930337E+235
-1.25617351166869E+264
 1.58370933499389E-242
 6.19284549187335E-245
-2.92969500042228E+254
-5.90042665390976E+226
 3.11954507295188E-273
 3.06831908609091E-217
 NaN
 2.77113146323761E-302
 6.76597919848376E-306
-1.55843653898344E+291
```

These are the firs few of the array in those limits is the rest of array too.

My conclusion of this is that i have some sort of code malfunction but i can seem to be able to find it.
Any help would be appreciated.

And the second question, because i'm only providing real data to the FFT algorithm in the response vector should i expect only Real part data too??

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you mean 16 bits per sample and 16 kbits/s rather than bytes?

Comment: Bits sorry for the typo i'm on this for the last three days and quite honestly i don't know what else to try.

Comment: @vlad_d26 Hm, I'm no expert at the WAV format, but 16 bit samples should most likely be bitconverted to `short` (ToInt16), not `double`. Also, if I remember correctly, BitConverter endian-ness depends on the CPU it runs on, so beware of problems with getting that wrong.

Comment: What language are you using? C#?

Comment: I run it on Intel machine , intel processors are little-endian and also tried handling for byte significance as for the conversion ToSingle is more like it, but thanks.

Comment: dbaupp, Yes I'm using c#

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson to Single will return a single precision floationg point number form 4 byts exactly as data is stored in to the wav file if i use integer here i will lose the rational part of the number.

Comment: @vlad_d26 Float (Single) is indeed a valid type to store in a WAV, but it requires 32 bits per sample, and your question states 16. I'd double check the contained type, it may very well be your problem.

Comment: No the results still deviate for a great deal, i 've tried it with integers and the spectrum i get is not from this universe. I'm stomped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to find out what was going wrong it seems that i didn't accounted for the pulse code modulation of the signal in the data representation, and because i found many unanswered questions here on wave file preparing for Fourier transformation here is the code in a function that prepares the wave file.

```
public static Double[] prepare(String wavePath, out int SampleRate)

    {
        Double[] data;
        byte[] wave;
        byte[] sR= new byte[4];
        System.IO.FileStream WaveFile = System.IO.File.OpenRead(wavePath);
        wave = new byte[WaveFile.Length];
        data = new Double[(wave.Length - 44) / 4];//shifting the headers out of the PCM data;
        WaveFile.Read(wave,0,Convert.ToInt32(WaveFile.Length));//read the wave file into the wave variable
        /***********Converting and PCM accounting***************/
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - i * 4; i++)
        {
            data[i] = (BitConverter.ToInt32(wave, (1 + i) * 4)) / 65536.0;
            //65536.0.0=2^n,       n=bits per sample;
        }
        /**************assigning sample rate**********************/
        for (int i = 24; i < 28; i++)
        {
            sR[i-24]= wave[i];
        }
        SampleRate = BitConverter.ToInt32(sR,0);
        return data;
    }
```

all you need to do now is to send the sample rate and the returned result to your FFT algorithm.
The code is not handled so do your own handling as needed.
I has been tested for phone recordings, of busy, ringing and speech, it functions correctly.